# Effect of letting unactivated cyberware work as "glitched" on game balance in Sixth World v26

Tags: house-rules, balance, dungeon-world, shadowrun

In Sixth World (v26), an unofficial Shadowrun hack of Dungeon World (by Chris Clouser and Tanner Yea) activating cyberware that is not *always on* and that does offer mechanical benefits (related to moves or defenses) costs a point of Edge. Some critics think this makes cyberware too underpowered. On the other hand, eliminating the Edge cost might be too much, though. A "golden middle" could be to allow the cyberware in question to function all the time, though only imperfectly if Edge is not spent on their activation. My question is:

**What game effect would allowing unactivated cyberware to work as "glitched" have on game balance in Sixth World v26?**

(Mind you, I haven't tried this system yet, am just considering options since the official SR books that I bought over the years feel too rules heavy these days, and SR:Anarchy -- whose pdf I also bought -- is... well, not what I expected, unfortunately.)

Comment: Considering DW is just a hack of AW, perhaps instead we just need a new [sixth-world] tag to replace [homebrew] [dungeon-world].

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That might be a good idea, yes. (Even if DW seems to have grown quite big in its own right, becoming an official product, etc.)

Comment: True! I maybe should have said "was"… In any case, the litmus test that just occurred to me is whether anyone with only DW knowledge could answer this, and my thought in that regard is "I can't make heads nor tails of this", so I think a new tag does make sense. No game is too small to have a tag, I imagine.

Comment: I agree that we should just make a new tag, and from my little knowledge of DW I don't remember there being anything like Edge in it so at least that part of it is unlikely to require DW-only expertise (I believe that is a Shadowrun TTRPG thing they added to the hack)

Comment: You've made up a house rule and are asking us if it works?

Comment: @okeefe yes. isn't that what the house-rules tag is for? :)

Comment: @okeefe to be more precise, I'm asking all those who consider themselves experts in running this Sixth World DW variant, obviously. :)

Comment: @OpaCitiZen Fair enough.

Comment: @OpaCitiZen Have you looked at [The Sprawl](http://www.ardens.org/games/the-sprawl/)? Note that it's rethemed AW instead of a DW hack.

Answer (score 2):

### Worth a shot, but might not always be possible.

Always-on ware has a 2x cost modifier. I'm not sure exactly what cost modifier "glitches your roll unless you spend Edge" should have, but 0.5x doesn't sound beyond the pale. Just keep in mind:

- as this ware is always-on, you can't choose not to use it.
- not all ware is necessarily associated with one kind of roll or another. What happens with something like a vocal modulator, which just changes your voice? Glitch any roll that involves talking? Or is that more acceptable to be activated by Edge?

It might be better to formalize the "glitch unless Edge" effect as *unreliable* and go over the list of cyberware to see which entries that aren't already *always-on* make sense as *always-on unreliable*.

Comment: #2[Meet the Pack](https://youtu.be/6CeG9Y9s_Fo?t=26)